(gvt-apex) Intermittent connectivity issues with Apexcloud
We have random api call connections to APEX Cloud which is extremely unstable and frequently ending with failures. Those API is failing with frequent 447 error.
We are expecting 100% successful calls based on http 200 returns.

We can use the troubleshooting documentation provided to review the different types of error codes when consuming JWT-protected APIs in APEX Cloud.
In your particular example, we are dealing with JWT error code 447, which indicates that your JWT token has an:

Invalid exp claim. Please ensure that exp claim exists and JWT is not expired.

When generating your JWT token, do ensure that you follow the intended specification of the exp claim:

exp: This is the Unix epoch time in seconds of the expiry time of this JWT. The time zone is in UTC. The time cannot be more than 180 seconds from the iat (issued at claim).

These are the resources that you can use to further help your troubleshooting:

Official documentation for JWT in APEX Cloud
Hands-on learning for JWT in APEX Cloud

